# Transform Collection observable in Reactive X Java

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a block of code that transforms a block of List[VideoDetails] into a VideoGrid using a couple map statements with [ReactiveX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava):

```
feedService.loadVideoDetailsFeed(things)
            .map(new Func1<List<VideoDetails>, List<Video>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Video> call(List<VideoDetails> details) {
                    return Lists.transform(details, new Function<VideoDetails, Video>() {
                        @Override
                        public Video apply(VideoDetails input) {
                            return input.getVideo();
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<List<Video>, VideoGrid>() {
                @Override
                public VideoGrid call(List<Video> videos) {
                    //stuff
                }
            })
```

As you can see, I'm using a Guava transform in one of the map statements to go from List[VideoDetails] to List[Video].  I would assume there is a better way through ReactiveX to accomplish this transformation?  I was looking through the [transforming section](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#transforming) of the docs but I might be too green with ReactiveX to know what to use here.

The above code snippet works, I would just rather do it in the correct way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to keep the buffered aspect of the VideoInfo stream to create the VideoGrid.  So if that's the case, then the only way to stay with Rx the whole way would be to needlessly turn those sublists into observables and then map/transform the inner observable, only to collapse them back to lists when you create the VideoGrid. The way you're doing it now is probably the most pragmatic.

If you happen to be using Java 8, you can ditch Guava and the inner class:

```
return details.stream().map(VideoDetails::getVideo).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit** 
Here is a way to do it staying in Rx

```
        feedService.loadVideoDetailsFeed(things)
               .flatMap(new Func1<List<VideoDetails>, Observable<List<Video>>>() {
                   @Override
                   public Observable<List<Video>> call(final List<VideoDetails> videoDeets) {
                       return Observable.from(videoDeets).map(new Func1<VideoDetails, Video>() {
                           @Override
                           public Video call(final VideoDetails videoDetails) {
                               return videoDetails.getVideo();
                           }
                       }).toList();
                   }
               })
               .map(new Func1<List<Video>, VideoGrid>() {
                   @Override
                   public VideoGrid call(List<Video> videos) {
                       return VideoGrid.fromListOfVideos(videos);
                   }
               });
```

And here is a way that will generate less garbage.  The actual observable query is more readable but it is more code overall.

```
private static Func1<VideoDetails, Video> _getVideo = new Func1<VideoDetails, Video>() {
    @Override
    public Video call(final VideoDetails videoDetails) {
        return videoDetails.getVideo();
    }
};
private static Func1<List<VideoDetails>, Observable<List<Video>>> _mapVideoDetailsToVideos = new Func1<List<VideoDetails>, Observable<List<Video>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Video>> call(final List<VideoDetails> videoDeets) {
        return Observable.from(videoDeets).map(_getVideo).toList();
    }
};
private static Func1<List<Video>, VideoGrid> _buildVideoGridFromVideos = new Func1<List<Video>, VideoGrid>() {
    @Override
    public VideoGrid call(List<Video> videos) {
        return VideoGrid.fromListOfVideos(videos);
    }
};

private static void yourFunction(final VideoDeetsSource feedService, String things) {
    feedService.loadVideoDetailsFeed(things)
               .flatMap(_mapVideoDetailsToVideos)
               .map(_buildVideoGridFromVideos);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Glad to know I wasn't missing something obvious. At large scale do you think it would be more performant to do it in the (albeit more obtuse) way you and krp describe?

Comment: I added some code that shows you how you could stay in Rx the whole time, but it will generate more garbage than using Guava.  The whole Observable.from().map().toList() creates a lot of temporary objects.  Either way whether you go with the all-Rx method or stay with Lists.transform() you should cache your selector/transformer function as   a static field to make sure that the anonymous innerclass is not instantiated on each datum.

Comment: As for runtime performance, you'd have to profile the code in the context of your system to get a meaningful answer to that

Comment: Awesome. Makes much more sense now.  Understood that the performance would depend on my code.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.  and FWIW, I found when I did some timing that if creating the VideoGrid did any real work, then then runtime difference of the two approaches was negligible.  On the other hand, if creating the VideoGrid was very fast then the Guava approach was about 2x as fast as the all-Rx approach

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the rx style you can use example below :

**edit**

```
feedService.loadVideoDetailsFeed(things)
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<VideoDetails>, Observable<Video>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Video> call(List<VideoDetails> videoDetailsList) {
                return Observable.from(videoDetailsList).map(new Func1<VideoDetails, Video>() {
                    @Override
                    public Video call(VideoDetails videoDetails) {
                        return videoDetails.getVideo();
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .toList();
```

Comment: Testing this out, it doesn't look like this compiles.  It seems type parameter 1 of Func1 should match argument 1 of the call method.  Is there a method similar to toList() but which does the inverse?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do :

- Starting with a `Observable<List<VideoDetails>>` then transform it to `Observable<VideoDetails>`.
- Transform this `Observable<VideoDetails>` to `Observable<Video>`.
- The last step : transform this `Observable<Video>` to `Observable<List<Video>>`.

This is very easy with RxJava (using the Java8 syntax)

```
feedService.loadVideoDetailsFeed(things) // Observable<List<VideoDetails>>
           .flapMap(Observable::from) // Observable<VideoDetails>
           .map(details -> details.getVideo()) // Observable<Video>
           .toList() // Observable<List<Video>>
           .map(/* doYourStuff */)
           .subscribe();
```